# Kibana - given an index, how to find saved objects relying on it?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

In Kibana I have many dozens of indices.
Given one of them, I want a way to find all the saved objects (searches/dashboards/visualizations) that rely on this index.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already explore .kibana index object? You want the theory / modelisation, or some requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the document ID of your index pattern and then use that to search your `.kibana` index

```
  {
    "_index" : ".kibana",
    "_type" : "index-pattern",
    "_id" : "AWBWDmk2MjUJqflLln_o",          <---- take this id...
```

You can use this query on Kibana 5:

```
GET .kibana/_search?q=AWBWDmk2MjUJqflLln_o   <---- ...and use it here
```

You'll find your visualizations:

```
  {
    "_index" : ".kibana",
    "_type" : "visualization",
    "_id" : "AWBZNJNcMjUJqflLln_s",
    "_score" : 6.2450323,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "CA groupe",
      "visState" : """{"title":"XXX","type":"pie","params":{"addTooltip":true,"addLegend":true,"legendPosition":"right","isDonut":false,"type":"pie"},"aggs":[{"id":"1","enabled":true,"type":"sum","schema":"metric","params":{"field":"XXX","customLabel":"XXX"}},{"id":"2","enabled":true,"type":"terms","schema":"segment","params":{"field":"XXX","size":5,"order":"desc","orderBy":"1","customLabel":"XXX"}}],"listeners":{}}""",
      "uiStateJSON" : "{}",
      "description" : "",
      "version" : 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta" : {
        "searchSourceJSON" : """{"index":"AWBWDmk2MjUJqflLln_o","query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":[]}"""
                                                   ^
                                                   |
                               this is where your index pattern is used
      }
    }
  },
```